# trigger click event in iframe parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="main">
    <a id="mainp" >Parent Window</a>

    <iframe id="iframeindex" src="iframeindex.html" >

    </iframe>
</div>

<script>
     $(function() {
        $('#mainp').live('click', function(e) {
            alert("hi");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

iframeindex source:

```
<a id="child1" class="test" href="a.html">aa</a>    

<script>
    $(function() {          
        $('.test').click(function(e){           
            $('#mainp', window.parent.document).css('color', 'red').trigger('click');

            e.preventDefault();
        })
    });
```

CSS is getting applied on parent window link but click event is not getting trigger.
How can i send trigger event to parent window.

Comment: Please be kind to your reader and spend some time to clean up your code. Consistent formatting and indentation go a long way!

Comment: What does `window.parent.$('#mainp').click()` get you?

Comment: What if the parent iframe doesn't have jquery running?

Answer (score 20):

```
window.parent.$('#mainp').trigger('click');
```

or

```
window.parent.$('#mainp').click();
```

Comment: This answer made the assumption they were on the same domain...should have specified.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the following format where other options didn't work.

```
    if ($("#maip", window.parent.document).length > 0){
        $("#mainp", window.parent.document).click();
```