# How to run JavaScript on parent page from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a top bar on a website that is imported using an iframe. When they click a gear icon in the top bar, a modal opens. I want the modal to open in the parent page, and not the header. Is there a way to do this so that it would pop up on the parent page instead of the header?

Comment: I think this should let you pass a message to your parent and then let it open the modal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522722/event-triggering-from-iframe/23585038

Comment: @msenne that doesn't work in my case, as I need to run a javascript function from the iframe imported onto the page through an extension point.