# Edge bug? Can't execute click() in parent iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, microsoft-edge

EDIT: This appears only to be a problem with clicking the Cancel button, which has an onclick method onclick="window.close()". You can programmatically click the OK button, which has onclick="this.form.elements['button'].value = 'OK'". Does anyone have any idea why the OK button would work, but not the Cancel button?

I have two iframes with the same origin. When the cancel button is clicked in the nested iframe, it calls jQuery .click() on the cancel button in the parent iframe, causing it to close. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Edge, nothing happens when you click the cancel button in the nested iframe (that is, the .click() on the parent iframe's cancel button is not executed).

I know that I am addressing the correct element, because I can hide the parent cancel button from the nested iframe without any problem using .hide(). I have tried various suggested solutions without any success (e.g., [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521947/trigger-click-event-in-iframe-parent-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521947/trigger-click-event-in-iframe-parent-window))

Here is my code, with the remains of various suggested proposals commented out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var debug = true;
var cancelBtn = $("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']");
var listenType = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('edge') != -1) ? 'mouseup' : 'click';
if (debug) console.log("listenType = " + listenType);
cancelBtn.on(listenType, function() {
    if (debug) console.log("About to close parent view. cancel_btnName length = " + $(parent.document).find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").length);

    if ($(parent.document).find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").length > 1) {
        $(parent.document).find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName'].last()").click();
    } else {
        var parentDoc = $(parent.document);
        //parentDoc.find("input.Button[name='ok_btnName']").focus();
        //parentDoc.find("body").click();
        //parentDoc.find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").focus();
        parentDoc.find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").trigger('click');
        //$("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']", window.parent.document).click();
        //parent.$('body').find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").trigger('click');
        //parentDoc.find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").click();
        //$(parent.document).find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").trigger("click");
        //$(parent.document).find("input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']").hide();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Can you trigger an event in the parent? If so fire an event on the parent. `$(parent.document).trigger('iframe_close');` and listen to it on the parent `$(document).on('iframe_close', function() { $('input.Button[name='cancel_btnName']').trigger('click');});`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to trigger an event. With your first line in the chile iframe and this code in the parent window, nothing was printed to the console:

Comment: $(document).on('iframe_close', function() {
  console.log("event iframe_close was triggered");
  $('input.Button[name="cancel_btnName"]').trigger('click');
 });

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example( using [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thanks. I'll need to talk to our vendor. There's more going on than meets the eye at first.